# TypeScript: can't write heterogeneous array literals

Tags: typescript

what type asserts do i need to get this to compile?

```
class Foo {}
class Bar {}

var f =
[
    [Foo, [1, 2, 3]],
    [Bar, [7, 8, 9]],
];
```

error:

```
Incompatible types in array literal expression
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like typescript *does* have heterogeneous arrays now.  So, since
this question came up first when I looked for this, and since it's hard
to find it otherwise, here how this code can be written now:

```
class Foo {}
class Bar {}

var f: [Foo|Bar, number[]][] =
    [[new Foo(), [1, 2, 3]],
     [new Bar(), [7, 8, 9]]];
```

(Now if this goes down the road of type syntax mimicking expressions,
the type would also get a syntax of `[Foo|Bar, [...number]][]`...)

It even works with function arguments, so this typechecks fine:

```
function foo([obj,nums]: [Foo|Bar, number[]]) {
  for (let i of nums) console.log(`i = ${i}`);
}

f.forEach(foo);
```

and the extreme version:

```
f.forEach(([obj,nums]: [Foo|Bar, number[]]) => {
  for (let i of nums) console.log(`i = ${i}`); });
```

Answer (score 16):

This will work:

```
class Foo {}
class Bar {}

var f: any[][] = [
    [Foo, [1, 2, 3]],
    [Bar, [7, 8, 9]],
];
```

This says you have a two-dimensional array whose values can be anything (Foo, Bar, other arrays, etc). You could also use a type assertion for your nested arrays:

```
class Foo {}
class Bar {}

var f = [
    [<any>Foo, [1, 2, 3]],
    [<any>Bar, [7, 8, 9]],
];
```

The presence of a single any in the inner array forces the compiler to infer its type as any[].

Comment: I'd prefer if arrays were inferred to be any[] by default. These are JavaScript `[object Array]`s here, not `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: this actually means that Typescript is not a superset of Javascript

Comment: @JasonDenizac I personally disagree, generally in TypeScript it is a mistake to have heterogeneous array, and you are much less likely to screw yourself over if you have to explicitly say the ways in which it is heterogeneous.

Comment: It is now possible to write a proper type for this, see my answer.  (And @semicolon, this is wrong if only because TS has an explicit goal to allow plain JS idioms (and to return two (different) values it's certainly useful to slap an array around them instead of an object wrapper).)

Answer (score 2):

As of Typescript 1.4 you can do type unions. I was able to accomplish this like so:

```
function zip<T, X> (array1: T[], array2: X[]): (T|X)[][] {
    return array1.map(function (v: T, i: number) { return [v, array2[i]]; });
}
```

The specific type you would be looking for in your case would be:

```
(Foo|Bar|number[])[][]
```

Or:

```
(typeof Foo|typeof Bar|number[])[][]
```

Comment: This is still a homogeneous array.  (Eg, you still need a redundant check before you iterate over the second element which IIUC is always an array.)